# How to nslookup multiple servers/websites

Tags: linux, bash, server, dns, nslookup

I am trying to gather the list of dns servers from multiple sites in linux but I am not sure how to do it without manually typing each url in. I want to get the nameservers but again, I want to do multiple values like getting the results for facebook.com, google.com and twitter.com.

```
nslookup -type=ns google.com

Non-Authoritative answer: google.com = nameserver ns1.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop.  This can be saved in a script, or used directly on the command line.

```
for SITE in facebook.com google.com twitter.com
do 
    nslookup "$SITE" > "$SITE.out"
done
```

If you do not mind having the entire thing displayed in your terminal, you could do:

```
for SITE in facebook.com google.com twitter.com
do 
    echo "----- $SITE -----"
    nslookup "$SITE"
done
```